# decouple copy paste and select paste in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, copy, paste

after setup, virtualbox natively shares the copy buffer between vm and remote or local host machine but doesn't share the select buffer. It also overrides whatever is on the vm's select buffer every time a copy is made on host's side and vice versa.

I have virtualbox running with ubuntu as the os for both the host and guest machines.

The question is, is it possible to decouple the copy and select buffers so that the select buffer exists independently on both the vm and host while copy buffer is shared?